# My fonts are not loading in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to call my local fonts from my local folder called fonts but those are not loading in css and below is

```
@font-face {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova';
    src: url('fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your paths, Best practices is to always use a relative paths

- Root

  - index.html
  - **add_ons**

    - **style_sheets**

      - style.css
    - **sources**

      - **fonts**

        - ProximaNova-Regular.woff2
        - ProximaNova-Regular.eot
        - ProximaNova-Regular.woff
        - ProximaNova-Regular.ttf
        - ProximaNova-Regular.svg

Should be like,

```
@font-face {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-family: 'ProximaNova';
        src: url('../sources/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.eot');
        src: url('../sources/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('../sources/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
          url('../sources/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
           url('../sources/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.svg') format('svg');
    }
```